# \includegraphics in tikz without offset

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, positioning

I've been trying to precisely position an image in an `article` using tikz, but when I use `\includegraphics` on a node I've defined, there is some small offset both vertically and horizontally. I would like the code below to produce a black rectangle that fits perfectly inside the lines I drew, and would prefer it if I didn't just have to manually add negative shifts to make things line up by eye.

Any help or insights are appreciated!

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[left=0in,top=0in,right=0in,bottom=0in,verbose,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
%
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
 \node [shift={(-8.5in,-11in)}]  at (current page.north east)
 {%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
% 
     \path (0.5in,0.25in)  node (p1) {}; 
     \path (3in,0.25in)    node (p2) {}; 
     \path (8in,0.25in)    node (p3) {}; 
     \path (0.5in,3.75in)  node (p4) {}; 
     \path (8in,3.75in)    node (p5) {}; 
     \path (0.5in,10.75in) node (p6) {};  
     \path (3in,10.75in)   node (p7) {};  
%
    \node[anchor=south west] at (p1.center)
     {\includegraphics[width=2.5in,height=3.5in]{./black.png}}; 
%
     \draw[very thin, blue!50] (p1.center)  to (p3.center);   
     \draw[very thin, blue!50] (p4.center)  to (p5.center);   
     \draw[very thin, blue!50] (p1.center)  to (p6.center);
     \draw[very thin, blue!50] (p2.center)  to (p7.center);
% 
     \end{tikzpicture}
 };
%
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] at (p1.center)
     {\includegraphics[width=2.5in,height=3.5in]{./black.png}};`

Comment: Aha! Thank you!

Comment: Not related, but it is generally admitted that nesting `tikzpicture` inside a `tikzpicture` is not a good idea and can lead to unintended issues.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because solved in comments.